# Mongodb $lookup nested objects with pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pipeline, lookup

I have the following schema `Thing`:

```json
{
  name: "My thing",
  files: [
    {
      name: "My file 1",
      versions: [
        {
          file_id: ObjectId("blahblahblah")
        },
        {
          file_id: ObjectId("blahblahblah")
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "My file 2",
      versions: [
        {
          file_id: ObjectId("blahblahblah")
        },
        {
          file_id: ObjectId("blahblahblah")
        },
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

And then I a have a `File` schema:

```json
{
  _id: ObjectId("blahblah"),
  type: "image",
  size: 1234,
}
```

The `file_id` in the `Thing` schema is a REF to the `_id` of the `File` schema.

I want to `$lookup` all the files inside my `Thing`. So I started with this:

```json
{
  "$lookup": {
    "from": "files",
    "let": { "files": "$files" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$files.versions.file_id" ] } } }.
    ],
    "as": "files.versions.file"
  }
}
```

But it's obviously wrong. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when we `$$files.versions.file_id` access ids it will return array of array of ids so `$in` will not match nested array of ids,

I can see you are trying to project file details in same nested level, so direct lookup will not set that detail in nested array, you have to deconstruct the array first before set files details,

- `$unwind` deconstruct `files` array
- `$unwind` deconstruct `versions` array
- `$lookup` with `files` collection and pass `files.versions.file_id` as localField
- `$unwind` deconstruct `files.versions.file_id` array
- `$group` by `name` and `file name` and re-construct `versions` array
- `$group` by `name` only and reconstruct `files` array

```
  { $unwind: "$files" },
  { $unwind: "$files.versions" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "files",
      localField: "files.versions.file_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "files.versions.file_id"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$files.versions.file_id" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        name: "$name",
        file_name: "$files.name"
      },
      versions: { $push: "$files.versions" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.name",
      files: {
        $push: {
          name: "$_id.file_name",
          versions: "$versions"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/azpzpQm1qVy)